# Solving an initial value problem

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, homework

[image]

I am generally confused on how to solve this problem, I was given very little background on how to solve an initial value problem through Mathematica.

I believe I have created the graph below properly, correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so first, you did a relative good job if this is your first time with Mathematica/Programming.

You used [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) to get the Solution which is good and right. But I would say, you take a look at [`DSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html). Its the same Function, its just putting out the solution with nothing else (No list, no Rule) which is what you want here.

> If you still want to use DSolve, you have to substitute the y[x] with
>   a [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and a [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to get rid of the List. This looks like this:
>
> ```
> sol = (y[x] /. DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2*y[x], y[1] == 3}, y[x], x])[[1]]
>
> 3 E^(-(1/3) + x^3/3)
> ```
>
> (You dont need the Part (...[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meK7p.png)]) here since Plot could handle it)

Second you used VectorPlot. But for the Phase-Portrait i'd recommend [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html).

You can now Plot your Field, Plot your solution (with a simple [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)) and combine these two with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

This looks like this:

```
sol = DSolveValue[{y'[x] == x^2*y[x], y[1] == 3}, y[x], x]

Show[StreamPlot[{1, x^2*y}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -8, 8}], 
Plot[sol, {x, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

> [image: Fieldplot]

(I also added a `PlotStlye->Red` to the Plot to get a good contrast between the field plot and ODE-Plot)

Hope this helps

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much

Comment: I am reading the instructions where it says my name for the each function. So should it look like this: sol=Mike[x_]=y[x] /. DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 y[x], y[1] == 3}, y[x], x][[1]]? I found that this code prints an output that seems correct I just don't know what function they want me to name. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can done by [utilizing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137595/plotting-phase-plane-with-streamplot-function/137602#137602) the `StreanPoints` option, which takes the initial condition as an input and select the streamline passing through the initial condition,

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2*y

StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -4, 3}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{{1, 3}, Red}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]